# Concatenated Cell Reference using the result of a COUNTA function

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am having some trouble with a formula. I am trying to use a COUNT function to set a range reference. Thank you.

=COUNTIF(G1:"G"&COUNTA(A1:100),1)

Comment: the formula is not right can you explain with example

Comment: I have a list of names in column A.

I have a list of values in column G.

I would like the formula to search a range and count the number of values in column G that equal 1.

Am I going about this the hard way?

Comment: Do you have empty cells in column A between your Data?

Comment: I updated my answer with countifs

Comment: I prefer Scott's answer..........consider changing the Answer checkmark to his answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use non volatile INDEX.

```
=COUNTIF(G1:INDEX(G:G,COUNTA(A1:A100)),1)
```

Comment: This option also worked. I wish I could Green check more than 1 answer! Thank you so much for your time and help!

Comment: @ChrisLee  This answer is better than mine....consider giving it the Green check instead of mine.

Comment: @Gary's Student Understood. You still have my appreciation.

Answer (score 2):

consider:

```
=COUNTIF(G1:INDIRECT("G"&COUNTA(A1:A100)),1)
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much. I tried to use INDIRECT earlier and messed up the CONCAT. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

From a Comment by OP:

> I would like the formula to search a range and count the number of values in column G that equal 1

Based on Q, range seems to be first 100 rows.

I must be missing the point by a mile because:

```
=SUMIF(G1:G100,1)
```

seems to solve what little I understand of (and there is in) the Q (plus a Comment).

Answer (score 0):

use indirect or offset

```
=countif(G1:indirect("G"&COUNTA(A1:100)),1)
```

OR

```
 =countif(offset(G1,0,0,COUNTA(A1:100),1),1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
=COUNTIF(INDIRECT("G1:G"&COUNTA(A1:A100)),1)
```

You are missing Indirect
A1:A100 (A1:100) is not a range for countA
CountA will count non empty cells in column A
**Update**
You can use another simple formula

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,"<>",G:G,1)
```

Countifs will count the 1 in column G if the corresponding A <>""

Or:

```
=COUNTIFS(A1:A100,"<>",G1:G100,1)
```